# How to add custom fonts in React Native Version 0.70.5

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to load custom fonts in my React Native App. However, I am using version 0.69 and I don't know how to add them anymore, because:

- link and unlink commands have been removed in the favour of autolinking
- Removed assets and hooks from react-native.config.js – you'll need to remove these properties from your    config

So how can this now be done in Android and iOS now?

Comment: This should help you - https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-custom-fonts-react-native/

Answer (score 1):

You can add your font files to the project's main assets folder, it should automatically link for you but you should still run the following command from your terminal: `npx react-native-asset`.

Afterwards, you would be able to use your font like normal: `fontFamily: 'Awesome-Font'`